# files changed from644 to 755 is not safe?

Tags: cpanel

I changed by accident all files on 2 very big websites to be 755. Previous was 644, at least on some, what I do not know for sure is that all were 644 before.
Unfortunately these files were uploaded to the cpanel hosting.
I wonder if it's safe to have 755 permissions on files and I can just leave it that way, 
or should I change back to 644, am not fancy to do that incase some were not 644 before, suppose at least folders were not 644.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not safe to leave files in 0755, as you are turning on the execution bit.

The recommended file permission for WHM/cPanel hosting environment is 0644 for files and 0755 for directories.

Since you have accidentally made the changes, I would recommend running the below commands to fix the file and directory permissions.

```
find /path/to/your/public_html -type f ! -perm  644 -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
find /path/to/your/public_html -type d ! -perm  755 -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, thanks will do the change, however I need to change locally on my Mac first and then upload the change to cPanel.

Comment: I managed to do the change in Mac like this:
chmod 644 /Users/folder/web/*
find /Users/folder/web -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755